# log4cplus - flush file before writing in it

Tags: c++, logging, log4cplus

My need is quite simple:

with log4cplus, I'd like to be able to write a log in a log file and to flush the log file everytime before I write in it. This way, while I run my application, I will only have one single line in my log file.

I've tryed the append=False property, but it only flush the log file at startup.

I could do it by hand in C++ but I don't want to write C++ code as the product is already in prod.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: Flushing usually means something else: Writing all buffered data to the disk (etc.)

Comment: single line log file does not sound as something helpful... you can always tweak maximum log file size etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ImmediateFlush` property to force the file appender to flush after each event.

Comment: I tryed it, it doesn't work. As @deviantfan said, it looks like it's about flushing buffered data and not about clearing the log file

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood what you wanted. I think a logging library might not be what you want.